# Can I have two journeys in journey builder running at the same time using the same audience?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm running a journey at the moment which uses a DE called PAD_APPLICANT. I'm making another journey, which will use the same DE, but with a timed entry (eg it has to be a certain date for them to start in this one).

They are both fired by a fire event. At the moment, this fire event adds everyone in the DE to Journey 1. However, Journey 2 has entry criteria of the column [Event_Date] = today PLUS 7 days (basically, it's a 7-day reminder email for an event that's occurring).

I suppose my question is twofold - is it possible to do this without any adverse effects and if not, what would they be?

Also, for anyone who doesn't meet the Journey 2 criteria (ie it isn't their time to get the 7 day reminder yet), will that stop them permanently from entering the journey, or will it check again the next time the event is fired?